# How to show submenu on product detail page

Tags: module, menu, module-display, administration, submenu

I am working in joomla version 3.1.1 with joomshopping. It is showing submenu fine on category view, but when I go to the product detail page the submenus are not being displayed.

Is there any way to show the submenus on the product detail page?
If I select the show on all pages option (for the module), then it shows submenus on all pages, but I only want to display them both on category and product detail page.

Answer (score 1):

I guess submenu is a module - **Modules** are displayed in specific pages, by assigning them on **menu items**. 
It's possible that you don't have a menu-item for the Product Details Page - if you do, then you need to assign the module to this menu-item as well.

It might also worth trying to use the "**exclude assignment**" option for your module:
Instead of using "**show on the selected menu items**", use "**show on all menu items except the selected**". Of course, you will have to select all the menu items that you don't want the module to appear.

Other things that could help:

Check to see, if Joomshopping is giving you options for using specific menu-item id for the product details page. If something like this exist, make sure you have a menu item created (even hidden) to hold the product-details page, and assign on this menu-item the modules you want to show.

Finally, the [**Advanced Module Manager**](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager) by NoNumber extends the core Moduler Manager, providing many more options for Module assignments, which may come handy in your case.